# iOS socket connection to Android through the same wifi

Tags: android, ios, sockets, nanohttpd

I have an iOS app and an Android app. The android app will act as "server" and the iOS app as "client". I want two cases:

1. To be able from the iOS app to request a file from the android app and download it on the iOS device.
2. To send a String or an XML file from the iOS app to the Android app, do some stuff in the android app and reply to iOS with a success message or so.

Can you please advice if I can do this directly though sockets or some workaround like creating an http server (like httpd-nano ) on the android app?

Comment: You can create a REST service and let the iOS app access it through nanohttpd.

Comment: Have you found a solution?...I am also looking for the same